# Any way to simplify comparing lists of Processes?

Tags: c#, list, process

I was just curious if there was a simplified way to write this bit of code, or more efficient.

I want to wait for a new notepad.exe to exist, add that process to a list of processes or list of process ids only if it is not already in the list, also remove any processes in that list that do not exist anymore. Then repeat in an endless loop.

```
public static List<int> Clients = new List<int>();
while(true)
{
    foreach (int r in Clients)
        if (!ProcessExists(r))
        {
            Clients.Remove(r);
            Console.WriteLine(r + " was removed.");
            break;
        }
    bool check = false;
    Process[] initial = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    foreach (Process i in initial)
    {
        foreach(int r in Clients)
        {
            if (i.Id == r)
            {
                check = true;
            }
        }
        if (check == false)
        {
            Clients.Add(i.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(i.Id + " was added.");
        }
        check = false;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(250);
}

private static bool ProcessExists(int id)
{
    return Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Any(x => x.Id == id);    
}
```

Comment: The Clients variable is declared outside of the method, I just show it above the while loop for clarity.

Comment: yes this is the actual code, and it is working, beacuse i break afterwards to avoid the Exception that is thrown that says list may have been modified.

Comment: Ahh... nevermind me, I didn't read that `break;`

Comment: You can use a HashSet instead of List to avoid duplicates.  So your last foreach could be reduced to one line of code: `if (Clients.Add(i.Id)) Console.WriteLine(i.Id + " was added.");` as a HashSets add doesn’t add duplicates and will tell you if there was one or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop that take care of deletion can be simpler using Linq:

```
Clients.RemoveAll(p => !ProcessExists(p));
```

Or this way, to keep the log:

```
Clients.RemoveAll(p => {
    if (!ProcessExists(p)) {
        Console.WriteLine(p + " was removed.");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

For the second loop, you can use `Contains()` method of the `List<>` class:

```
    Process[] initial = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    foreach (Process i in initial)
    {
        if (!Clients.Contains(i.Id))
        {
            Clients.Add(i.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(i.Id + " was added.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for.